# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with decimal

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a Stored Procedure which requires a structured parameter. I'm trying to call the stored procedure from my C# code and I get following error.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Operand type clash: datetime2 is
>   incompatible with decimal The data for table-valued parameter
>   "@TableType" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL
>   Server error is: 200, state: 7'

Below is my stored procedure which is available in the database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spProcessData
    @TableType AS dbo.TblTypeHourlyData READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


END
```

This is my table type script.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TblTypeHourlyData AS TABLE 
(
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    RecordDate DATETIME,
    Amount  DECIMAL(18,2)
)
GO
```

I call the SP by passing the required parameter (data table). However, it returns an error in the `var executeNonQuery = command.ExecuteNonQuery();` line.

```
        List<HourlyData> data = .................
        using (var connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "dbo.spProcessData";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                DataTable paramDT = new DataTable();
                using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data))
                {
                    paramDT.Load(reader);
                }

                var param1 = new SqlParameter("@TableType", SqlDbType.Structured)
                {
                    TypeName = "dbo.TblTypeHourlyData",
                    Value = paramDT
                };

                command.Parameters.Add(param1);
                connection.Open();
                var executeNonQuery = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // ERROR
                connection.Close();

                var value = executeNonQuery > 0;
                return value;
            }
        }
```

For the "data" variable, I already have a data set. `HourlyData` class has the same structure as the table type.

```
public class HourlyData
{
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? RecordDate{ get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal? Amount{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but did you check the Column Order of paramDT? Does it match your TblTypeHourlyData Order? Reading the error Message, I think its trying to put the date in the decimal place or the other way around.

Comment: What is the `RecordDate` data that you sent? Is that null or someting?

Comment: @SelimYıldız Yes, it can be null for some scenarios. 
Example record: 1/7/2020 7:22:15 AM

Comment: Do you get same error for  both case (sending null or `1/7/2020 7:22:15 AM` ) ?

Comment: Yes. It returns this error for every scenario. Same error !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the info [here](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/pull/73) you need to add an attribute so that the column order resulting from `ObjectReader.Create(data)`  is the same as expected in the TVP.

> If the attribute is not defined in the source class then alphabetical order is used

Comment: When I define the attribute with  [Ordinal(0)],  [Ordinal(1)] etc. it works !!! You're a lifesaver.